# Setting datasource JNDI in embeddable WebSphere EJB container

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, websphere, ejb-3.1

I am using the embeddable EJB container of WebSphere 8 to write some unit tests for my EJBs with JUnit4. I have a simple java project in MyEclipse where I reference the EJB project. The EJB project uses Hibernate 3.5 for persistence and the datasource JNDI in hibernate.cfg.xml is jdbc/connectionname. When it runs on standard WebSphere 8 I have set up the datasource through the web console and all works fine. On the embeddable container the datasource is set up in embeddable.properties with:

name again as jdbc/connectionname among other datasource info (username, password etc.) and
Bean.#TestProjectName#ClassNameForTests.ResourceRef.BindingName.jdbc/connectionname=jdbc/connectionname

My embeddable.properties is as follows:

```
DataSource.ds1.name=jdbc/connectionname
DataSource.ds1.className=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
DataSource.ds1.createDatabase=create
DataSource.ds1.databaseName=DBNAME
DataSource.ds1.user=dbusername
DataSource.ds1.password=dbpassword
DataSource.ds1.transactional=true
DataSource.ds1.createDatabase=create
```

The embeddable container starts successfully and the EJBs can be found successfully through JNDI but at the point where the method call is made I get the error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure:78 - Could not find datasource: jdbc/connectionname
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc not found in context "serverlocal:CELLROOT/SERVERROOT".
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1969)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1376)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1219)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1314)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `jdbc/connectionname` data source configured via embeddable properties?  See the [Embeddable EJB container configuration properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rejb_emconproperties.html) InfoCenter topic.  You properties should look something like this:

```
DataSource.ds1.name=jdbc/connectionname
DataSource.ds1.className=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource
DataSource.ds1.createDatabase=create
DataSource.ds1.databaseName=jtest1
```

If you already have this, can you show the properties you're using?  Note that Hibernate is not using your resource reference, so the ResourceRef.BindingName has no effect in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have this. Please check my updated question above for details.

Comment: Those properties look like they should work.  Is the embeddable.properties in the current working directory when the JVM is started?  What happens if you explicitly pass those properties to the EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(Map) method?

Comment: Thanks @bkail. Adding the properties as a map works fine. But now I am getting [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772266/websphere-embeddable-ejb-container-throws-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com) which I am not able to fix.

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, you should accept it (click the check box to the left of the answer).